# How to call execl() in C with the proper arguments?

Tags: c, exec, external, quotes, unistd.h

i have vlc (program to reproduce videos)
if i type in a shell:

/home/vlc "/home/my movies/the movie i want to see.mkv"

it opens up an reproduces the movie.

however, when I run the following program:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {

  execl("/home/vlc", "/home/my movies/the movie i want to see.mkv",NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

vlc opens up but doesn't reproduce anything. How can I solve this?

Things I tried:

I guessed

```
execl("/home/vlc", "/home/my movies/the movie i want to see.mkv",NULL);
```

was equivalent to typing in the shell:

```
/home/vlc /home/my movies/the movie i want to see.mkv
```

which doesn't work, so i tried

```
 execl("/home/vlc", "\"/home/my movies/the movie i want to see.mkv\"",NULL);
```

and vlc opens up but doesn't reproduce either.

Instead of writing NULL at the end I tried 0, (char*) 0, 1 .... not helpful.
Help!!!!

Comment: Why didn't you look at `errno` after the failed execl? It would have told you more about your problem. What has become of reading the man page for execl carefully? :-)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
execl("/home/vlc", 
  "/home/vlc", "/home/my movies/the movie i want to see.mkv", 
  (char*) NULL);
```

You need to specify all arguments, included `argv[0]` which isn't taken from the executable.

Also make sure the final `NULL` gets cast to `char*`.

Details are here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html

Comment: Why does /home/vlc need to be specified twice?

Comment: first one is the full path, second is process name, generally "vlc" is enough in the second parameter

Comment: It should be `... , (char*) NULL);`

Comment: @alk, indeed.  (But I wonder how many current implementations are there out which won't work with a naked NULL as defining NULL as (void*)0 or 0L became popular to make the absence of cast on NULL to work in practice with variadic functions; even passing a naked 0 will work on most if not all 32-bit ABI and, IIRC, some 64-bit one such as the one used by Linux).

Comment: Why do we have to cast NULL?

Comment: In case NULL is defined as 0 and sizeof(char*) != sizeof(int)

Comment: @AProgrammer That wouldn't conform to POSIX, which requires that `NULL` is `0` cast to `void *`.  <https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stddef.h.html>

Answer (score -1):

If you need just to execute your VLC playback process and only give control back to your application process when it is done and nothing more complex, then i suppose you can use just:

`system("The same thing you type into console");`

Comment: Between fixing the slight misunderstanding in the execl arguments and writing a function which will quote correctly so that the shell can undo the quote, I know what I prefer.

Comment: I think i get your point and your preferment is reasonable. But when dealing with such simple needs, is there any other benefits of using execl() instead of system(), besides avoidance of messing with escape sequence backslashes in system()?

Comment: There could be security reasons, if you have for example a string created like, `sprintf(buf, "ls -la %s", var)` which you execute with `system(buf)`, someone could give you a filename, `"somefile; rm -rf ~"`, for example.