# Parameter of Linux execl function

Tags: c, linux

The first parameter of execl is the path of the executable file, my question is that what if there is a space in the path?

My program fails when space exists.

Comment: try: escape it with `"\ "`

Comment: Show your source code. When does your program fail (when it is compiled, or while running)?

Comment: See [execl(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12596877/841108). Also, use `perror` (or show `errno`) on failure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call execl() in C with the proper arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596839/how-to-call-execl-in-c-with-the-proper-arguments)

Comment: The system call doesn't parse the strings given to it, i.e., doesn't split at whitespace or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what if there is a space in the path?

It does not matter, as the `exec*()` functions do not involve a shell or any kind of command interpreter which might choke on the space, or any other special character.

> My program fails when space exists.

Does `exec()` return? Which value do you find in `errno` or what does `perror()` print?

```
exec(....); /* exec*() function do ot return is successful. */
perror("exec() failed);
```