# unistd's execl() without passing any arguments

Tags: c, linux, unistd.h

In my code I need to execute `/bin/bash`, but I wan't to do it without passing any arguments to it. I wrote this:

```
execl("/bin/bash", NULL);
```

Then, through some research, I realized that I also need to add type cast:

```
execl("bin/bash", (char*) NULL);
```

but GCC is still giving me warnings:

```
main.c:18:5: warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 2) [-Wnonnull]
     if(execl("/bin/bash", (char*) NULL) == -1) {
     ^
main.c:18:5: warning: not enough variable arguments to fit a sentinel [-Wformat=]
```

What is the proper way of doing this, am I misunderstanding something, or am I using a completely wrong function call?

Comment: You've got a couple of substantially identical answers so far.  I'll observe that the classic way of getting a login shell was `execl("/bin/sh", "-sh", (char *)0)`, where the `-` indicated that it was a login shell.  Bash (and some other shells) have regularized it so that `execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-l", (char *)0)` is a login shell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are getting the warning because the convention is that the first argument is always the same as the path of the program being run, like this:

```
execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", (char*) NULL);
```

This is essentially what happens when you run a program without arguments in the shell.

This argument will go into the executed program's `argv[0]`, which it can use to check how it was run.

Comment: The convention is that the first arg is the full path as it was run, not just the filename.  You got it right in your example however.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html), `execl()` has the following defintion:

```
   int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...
                   /* (char  *) NULL */);
```

GCC is telling you the `execl()` function is expecting a non-NULL argument.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar problem. I found out that if I specified the full path to my exe (starting with /) neither execlp nor execv passed any argument. And also that I could not output anything to stderr.

Since I only want to replace my current process with a clone version of itself, I save and use the argv[0] of the parent as the 2 first arguments of execlp/v and everything is fine.

Answer (score -1):

The first two parameters of `execl()` should be the full path and then the process name.

At least that's how I interpreted it [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596839/how-to-call-execl-in-c-with-the-proper-arguments)

Comment: Why don't you use an official documentation link, like [this one `exec(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)?