# What exactly am I missing in executing find from C++?

Tags: c++

My effort is to use a piece of code in my program to find and copy certain files in my system.

The code I wrote meant to do that is:

```
void scan(int i)
{
pid_t parent = getpid();
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == -1)
{
    cout << "failed to fork" << endl;
    return;
}
else
{
    if(pid > 0)
    {
        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            execl("/usr/bin/find","find", "/", "-name", "'*.mp3'","-exec","cp","{}","/home/pi/Music","\\;",(char *)0);
            _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

return; }
```

Nevertheless, the system returns this:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

How exactly can I correct my execl command to execute this shell command:

```
find / -name '*.mp3' -exec cp {} /home/pi/Music \;
```

Comment: Note that you're not executing a "Bash command" here; `find` exists independently of Bash.

Comment: `cout << "failed to fork" << endl` a string literal is not a valid operand for `<<` in C.

Comment: 1) That's not C code 2) Your question is not related to C or C++. 3) Not related to programming.

Comment: @FreudianSlip - The first param to `execl` is the executable path.  The rest are the args; `argv[0]` is, by convention, the name of the executable.

Comment: @Olaf - In what way is not related to programming?

Comment: You don't need to quote the string `'*.mp3'` with the `'`

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: It is about the Unix `find` command, which is not related to programming in the context of this site.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - If you omit one of the \ then it won't compile...

Comment: @Olaf - if I use only the find command written above, it works fine. Only problem is to convert that to execl format. So I would personally say this is related to pragramming.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth True. I forgot that.  I was having way too much trouble trying to get one backslash in code ticks to show up properly.

Comment: I'll delete my wrong suggestion above so as not to confuse - sorry for the bum steer. Found this - it may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596839/how-to-call-execl-in-c-with-the-proper-arguments

Comment: Consider using the new [fileystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/experimental/filesystem) library if your compiler is modern enough.

Comment: @ZbyněkJakš: There is nothing about "execl format". You seems to have understood arguments are given one per parameter. So it **is** a problem with the syntax of `find` arguments you need to understand. "if I use only the find command written above" does not say anything else than you just used a pattern you don't really understand.

Comment: @Olaf true. Since this is my very first question here. Would you please recommend what should've be done differently when asking this question for future purposes? Thank you :)

Comment: How about RTF(ine)M?

Comment: @Olaf Don't get borderline (rude), I've been badly experiencing that ya know ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: OP asked for a tip what to do to ask better questions. Doing research before asking is the best way. The first address of research would be the manuals/documentation. So what's rude about this? I intentionally did not just write "RTFM" which some people consider being rude. If in doubt, assume the worst is a really bad attitude (I don't mean you).

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** - Remove the `\\` before the `;`.

In the context of a shell, a command is interpreted before the individual arguments being passed to the `find` executable.  `;` is a special character, so needs escaping in order to be interpreted as a literal (as it's a special character) - `find` actually only needs `;`.

However, you're not passing the arguments on the shell - `execl` passes the arguments directly to the target executable.  So there's no need to escape it.

---

As pointed out by @AndrewHenle in comments below, you'll also need to remove both the `'` from `'*.mp3'` for similar reasons.

Comment: You beat me to it.  I figured it had to be something to do with the backslashes.  The `'` chars in the `-name` argument will probably muck up `find`'s file name globbing, too.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Good call!  Have updated answer.

Comment: solved, thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

There is no Bash in sight, despite your question title. Yet you are using Bash-style quoting.

```
"'*.mp3'"
```

Your `find` will find nothing unless you have files with single quotation marks in their names. Use `"*.mp3"`.

```
"\\;"
```

`find` requires **a single semicolon** to terminate the `-exec` arguments. `\;` is the Bash way to use a literal semicolon. Normally `;` is a reserved character in Bash. Use a simple `";"`.

Comment: Thank you very much, problem solved.